# Unable to install PHP 5.5

Tags: php, ubuntu, installation, lamp

I had LAMP Server installed on Ubuntu 12.10 with PHP 5.3. I had to remove it so i used [this link](http://tuxtweaks.com/2010/01/how-to-uninstall-lamp-in-ubuntu-9-10-karmic-koala/).

Now I am trying to install LAMP with PHP 5.4 or higher using the ondrej ppa but i end up installing 5.3.10 again and again. I install using the below commands :

for 5.5 i tried,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5
```

and for 5.4 i tried,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5-oldstable
```

and then the regular update and install

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install php5
```

However in the end when i run `php -v` i see that the version installed is `5.3.10-1ubuntu3.19`

I have tried restarting the web server. still noting changes. I dont know where it is going wrong.

Comment: And why does that not work?

Comment: updated please check

Comment: Restart the terminal and check .